# "Остановите на остановке". Не верно? Как правильно сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте! Где-то услышала, что говорить "остановите на остановке" или "остановите на следующей остановке" говорить не правильно. Почему? И как правильно говорить?

Я теперь прошу "Остановите на следующей, пожалуйста". Верно ли это выражение? Ведь я просто опускаю слово "остановка".

Буду очень рада, если подскажете, полгода уже мучаюсь... :)

Answer (score 4):

Повторение однокоренных слов **не всегда следует рассматривать как стилистическую ошибку**. Многие стилисты справедливо считают, что **исключать из предложений однокоренные слова, заменяя их синонимами, не всегда необходимо:** в одних случаях это невозможно, в других это может привести к обеднению, обесцвечиванию речи. Несколько однокоренных слов в близком контексте стилистически **оправданы в том случае, если родственные слова являются единственными носителями соответствующих значений и их не удается заменить синонимами** (тренер - тренировать; выборы, избиратели - выбирать; привычка - отвыкнуть; закрыть - крышка; варить - варенье и др.). Как избежать, скажем, употребления однокоренных слов, когда надо сказать: На кустах расцвели белые цветы; Книга отредактирована главным редактором? [Подробнее здесь](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook028/01/part-003.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Говорили , что это ошибка, видимо из-за того, что *остановите на остановке* - это тавтология, а как учат в школе: тавтологий следует избегать. Правда, далеко не всякие расположенные рядом однокоренные слова будут ошибкой, и как раз расположение однокоренных глагола и существительного очень часто вполне соответствует всем нормам русского литературного языка (ср. *кататься на катке, качаться на качелях, играть в игрушки, видеть видение и др.*).

**Остановить на остановке** не плеоназм, так как на остановке можно не только останавливаться и останавливаться можно не только на остановке, а потому и речевой ошибки здесь нет.

*Остановите на следующей, пожалуйста* - тоже не является ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

Можете смело употреблять "Остановите не следующей [оcтановке]" 
Остановка тут используется в значении "остановочный пункт".
О плеоназме же можно было бы говорить (и то - не наверняка) лишь в случае использования слова "остановка" в значении "действие по глаголу останавливать". Но это значение плохо стыкуется с определением "следующий". Так что - без проблем.

По крайней мере - если Вас хорошо понимают водитель и окружающие.  
Вот вопрос понимания как раз не вполне однозначен. 
На моей памяти тому было несколько обсуждений.

Вот это, например, мною же и инициированное.
http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=266

Еще, ближе к конкретной теме:
http://forum.gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=1&i=21249&t=21249&v=f

И для коллекции
http://www.gramota.ru/forum/veche/40545/

К сожалению, не могу найти преинтереснейшего обсуждения (вернее сказать - опроса) о том, какой оборот в разных "городах и весях" используют для выражения данной просьбы. Кажется, было не на грамоте, а на каком-то еще форуме... если кто найдёт - буду весьма признателен.

Comment: У нас по просьбе перестали останавливать, останавливают на всех остановках, поэтому уже и не просят. На Сахалине была, там очень часто говорят без глагола: "На остановке, пожалуйста". Во Владивостоке говорят  название остановки: "Остановите на "Перевале".

Comment: В Архангельске дежурный вопрос любого кондуктора: "На Такой-то есть выходящие?" И далее она же водителю: "Нет". Или: "Выходят".